Looking for a psychological thriller
I watched a film before the year 2000 may be older.
There is a young man (18-25 years old) who is imprisoned in his mad neighbor's house.
There is also some mannequins at home.. Lifeless mannequin is eating food with his wife.
At the end of the film young man is killing him and he continues to stay that house.
I watched Turkish dubbing. Might be American or European movie.

sounds pretty freaky

I found it: Barracuda (1997)

A disturbed man (Jean Rochefort) with a mannequin wife becomes obsessed with a celebrity neighbor (Guillaume Canet).





This somehow sounds like the "tourist trap" where the a group of young people ( not one person) get trapped in a house of the killer..the killer's house is full of mannequins and he kills people and pours plaster on them turning them to mannequins. 
Not sure it's the same movie but if you are into creepy movies..the tourist trap is creepy

Thanks for the reply but that´s not the movie.
